# reset and start a new time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having hard time with reseting and starting a time interval function in javascript. Here is what I have worked so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#start").click(function(){
var valu = $("#in").val()
setInterval(function()
{   
console.log("hello")
},1000*valu)
})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in">
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Issue: When I input a new value and press start, the old interval keeps working instead of just the new one. For example, if you input 1 and press start the console outputs every 1 sec(good). However, If you input 10, instead of change to 10 sec interval it keeps the old 1 sec interval.
Goal: When I input a new value I want the old interval function to be removed and start a new interval.

Can you help me fix the issue?

Comment: hint: use `clearInterval` and the result of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(){
        var valu = $("#in").val();
        if(typeof myTimer != "undefined") {
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
 
        window.myTimer = setInterval(function()
        {   
            console.log("hello")
        },1000*valu);
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in">
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Store your `setInterval` in a global variable that can be accessed again the next time you call the function.

Then, you check if the variable is set and use `clearInterval` to stop the timer. It's then starting a fresh timer with your `setInterval` again.